# Jest test with seedrandom is unpredictable when source code changes, and test fails

Tags: node.js, typescript, random, jestjs

I've created a small reproducible test case here: https://github.com/opyate/jest-seedrandom-testcase

When I use [seedrandom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/seedrandom), I get predictable randomness, as proven by the test (when running it again and again with `npx jest`).

However, when I add inconsequential code to the test, it fails.

Can anyone shed some light as to why this might happen? And more importantly, how do I configure `jest` so the test doesn't fail when it changes?

Comment: Why do you think the test should not fail? `_.shuffle` randomizes the order of the array, and you're testing to make sure the result of `_.shuffle` yields the original ordering, which it most of the time will not.

Comment: It uses a seeded RNG.

Answer (score 1):

I have updated the repo at https://github.com/opyate/jest-seedrandom-testcase with an explanation:

Patching `Math.random` globally is not the right way to go, since Node/Jest internals possibly call `Math.random` and advances the RNG.

This is evidenced by uncommenting the line which adds another expectation to the test, as it advances the RNG another 9 times.

Sadly the code under test is not amenable to mocking/injection, but under normal circumstances, it would be advisable to mock `Math.random` like so:

```
import seedrandom from "seedrandom"
import { expect, test, jest } from "@jest/globals"

beforeEach(() => {
    const rng = seedrandom("hello.")
    jest.spyOn(global.Math, 'random').mockImplementation(rng)
})

afterEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global.Math, 'random').mockRestore()
})
```